# How to use a library project in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, library-project

I have been trying to add [this library project](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker) to my existing project in Android Studio. It's the first time I am going to use a library project and I am having tough time. I have looked around for many ways to do this from tutorials and posts around but couldn't get it done.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's already possible to add a library project via the IDE (-> without any problems).
I do this by configuring the gradle files of my project like this:

- create a folder in your root project directory named `libs`
- copy the folder `datetimepicker-library` to `libs`
- add this library in your `settings.gradle` with the following command:

  ```
  include ':libs:datetimepicker-library'
  ```
- go to your `build.gradle` file of your `AppProject` and add the following line to your `dependencies`:

  ```
  implementation project(':libs:datetimepicker-library')
  ```
- at least you have to sync your gradle files: Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Please try this. If you get errors please post the log file.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, but I couldn't get my build.gradle file to accept the 'compile project' line. Using "compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['datetimepicker-library'])" however, worked for me.

Comment: This last comment worked for me. With the original compile project... IDE complained of an undefined 'default' something.

Anyway: the library code doesn't appear on AS, so I guess I should open another Android Studio window to edit it.

Comment: Not working for me with Mapbox. Error:(13) No resource identifier found for attribute 'accessToken' in package 'com.example.myapp'

Comment: I followed these steps you mentioned and getting the error
Error:Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :libs:recognito.

I am trying to include the lib - https://github.com/amaurycrickx/recognito

Answer (score 8):

I did it this way ,

1. go to `project Structure` from `File` menu
2. Select `modules` from the left pane
3. press on `+'
4. complete the new module wizard steps 
     `Make sure to make the module package name same as the module you want to add`
5. again open `Project structure` as in step 1
6. select your project from the module list and on the right select dependencies
7. Click on the `+` icon from right
8. select module dependency and then select the newly added module.
9. copy files of the library project to the new directory created as  module
10. Done

**Step 1:**

[image: step 1]

**Step 2:**

[image: Step 2]!

**Step 3:**

[image: Step 3]

**Step 4:**

[image: **Step 4:**]

....

**Step 6 & 7:**

[image]

**Step 8:**
[image]

Comment: Any suggestion for adding https://github.com/saik0/UnifiedPreference ? I tried to follow this, but AS 0.5.1 kept complaining about a failed sync

Answer (score 0):

The other answers make it seem more difficult than it usually is. Just add a single `compile` line to your dependencies section of the app's build.gradle file.

In this case it is

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'
}
```

Gradle prompted me to sync and after I did so the library was automatically downloaded into my project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with solutions listed above is that you will end up with a clone of the library project in the app using the library. This complicates making updates to the library because you need to remove and re-import the module when you make changes.

The solution I found can *use the library project directly* from outside folder and it does not clone the original library files.

The solution is easy...

In **settings.gradle** add the following lines:

```
include ':commonwidgets'
project (':commonwidgets').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../SharedWidgets/commonwidgets')
```

and in the **build.gradle** `dependency` section add:

```
implementation project(path: ':commonwidgets')
```

Note: `commonwidgets` is the name of my library, you should replace the name and path according to your library name and path.

I hope this helps someone...

I really would have liked to have the library import from GitHub bit I refuse to pay $9/month for jetpack for private libraries.