# Importing github projects as library to existing project

Tags: github, android-studio

I am used to importing library as .jar file but I don't know how to use the projects from github like this: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/

I want to use it in my existing project. I tried including the project file in the dependencies but it's giving me some errors

Comment: Please be much more detailed about the content of your build files and what errors you're getting.

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34963958/926568

Answer (score 24):

I already explained [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377591/how-to-use-a-library-project-in-android-studio/20418060#20418060) how to use a project library in android studio.
But I know especially at the beginning it's not that easy until you understand the structur of AS-Projects. So here an explanation for your issue:

I'm adding project libraries to my projects by configuring the gradle files of my project like this:

- create a folder in your root project directory named 'libs'
- copy the complete folder 'library' of the  SlidingMenu project on git into 'libs'
- rename the folder 'library' that you just copied to e.g. "SlidingMenuLibrary" (just to avoid confusion)
- now add this library in your `settings.gradle` with the following command:

  ```
  include ':libs:SlidingMenuLibrary'
  ```
- go to your `build.gradle` file of your AppProject and add the following line to your 'dependencies':

  ```
  compile project(':libs:SlidingMenuLibrary')
  ```
- at least you have to sync your gradle files: Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Please try this. If you get errors please post the log file.

Comment: I used the method that you explained but I have this error:
Gradle 'Surprise' project refresh failed
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Comment: Used your method same error as above :  project refresh failed Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.