# Add GitHub library as dependency to Android Studio project

Tags: android, github, dependencies, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to implement ActionBar-PullToRefresh from https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/wiki/QuickStart-ABC. I just made the switch from Eclipse to Android Studio so I am totally new to AS and Gradle.

chrisbanes writes on the site:

> The easiest way to add ActionBar-PullToRefresh to your project is via
> Gradle, you just need to add the following dependency to your
> build.gradle:

```
dependencies {  
    mavenCentral()
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:+'
}
```

Does this mean that I don't have to download the library and Gradle takes care of it so that I always have the latest version? I just don't know where to put the above line. I have two gradle.build files one in my root that looks like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}
```

and the one in my project which looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Do I have to add a repository somewhere?

Comment: [Now the default is jcenter rather than Maven Central](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41847740/3681880)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It will work when you put this line in your project `build.gradle`, in the `dependencies` section:

```
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:+'
```

Also, add:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

So:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:+'
}
```

Gradle will download the needed resources automatically for you.

Comment: Also don't put it in the top-level build.gradle file -- the `repositories` and `dependencies` blocks there tell Gradle where to find the Android-Gradle plugin for the build system itself. Put it in the build.gradle file in your application module directory.

Comment: @ScottBarta Can I do this when the github project doesn't publish maven artifacts? As in, do this as a replacement to configuring it as a library project manually?

Comment: @dheeraj no, that's not possible.

Comment: howd you know the gradle link when the git part doest even share its gradle link

Comment: @ralphspoon When the project doesn't share the link, it probably doesn't have one. You can also search for the project on http://search.maven.org/.

Comment: If there's no Maven equivalent I would follow Method 2 in this link: https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 35):

Use https://jitpack.io/

```
allprojects {
    repositories { 
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
}
```

Comment: If you're getting failed to resolve errors, check out this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33059275/1641160

Answer (score 0):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts):

```kotlin
repositories {
    // Other repositories...

    maven("https://jitpack.io")
    // OR maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
}
```

There are two places inside which you can insert the above code block:

- The traditional way: inside top-level *build.gradle.kts* file
- New way: inside a `dependencyResolutionManagement {` block in *settings.gradle.kts* file;
  read more about this new feature at [Gradle user guide: Centralized Repository Declaration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:centralized-repository-declaration)