# Depend on GitHub repository in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I'm working on an Android app using Android Studio. So far I've been using `mavenCentral` to depend on all required libraries but now I'd like to add `bitcoinj-0.13-SNAPSHOT` dependency which is not yet present on `mavenCentral`.

Is it possible to somehow instruct `gradle` to get it directly from GitHub repo which is located here: https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/tree/master?

Comment: This has been answered already. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798694/add-github-library-as-dependency-to-android-studio-project

Comment: @Rene thanks but now I don't quite get what exactly I should write. I've tried `compile 'com.github.bitcoinj.bitcoinj:0.13-SNAPSHOT'` and it said "Failed to find"

Answer (score 4):

For projects that are not yet in mavenCentral you can use [JitPack](https://jitpack.io)

It will build the github repo for you and provide you with a dependency.