# Android Studio Compile Issue with plugin

Tags: android, gradle

Folks,

I am trying to use

```
com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.1
```

and I had several problems which prompted me to add:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
```

to my Project's build.gradle file, now when I try to sync my project I get the following message:

```
Error:Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Backup 2015\Development\AndroidStudioProjects\IKAG\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

This is my whole build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'





    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

//

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 20
  buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
}

dependencies {
// Other dependencies are omitted
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.1'
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add github library as dependency to Android-Studio project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798694/add-github-library-as-dependency-to-android-studio-project)