# Can't Compile Any External Libraries in Android Studio Project

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to add the [android-betterpickers](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers) library into my Android Studio project.

I'm getting this error every time:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration           ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:2.5.2.
     Required by:
         MyApp:app:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:2.5.2.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/code-troopers/betterpickers/library/2.5.2/library-2.5.2.pom'.
        > Failure initializing default system SSL context
```

I've tried the solutions stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26671662/3386826), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30991647/3386826), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21799030/3386826).

None of these worked for me.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 and Android Studio -v 1.5.1, my gut tells me this isn't an issue for Windows or iOS users or it would have more attention.

Here is my app/build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.boyd.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/library-1.0.19.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
}
```

Note: I had to use a jar file for the Volley library (the 'libs/library-1.0.19.jar' file) in the dependencies. That worked well. Unfortunately, [android-betterpickers](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers) doesn't have a public aar file available. If I can't find a fix/workaround, I may just have to request an aar file from them.

Google Play Services library works well, but perhaps it's because the library is downloaded directly from android servers, I can't say for sure.

Anyone know of a solution?

---

**UPDATE**

I found the aar file!

Located here: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/code-troopers/betterpickers/library/

for anyone that wants this particular library.

Gradle build successful after adding aar as library and using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28816265/3386826).

---

**UPDATE 4/11/16**

I ended up having to reinstall Ubuntu on my desktop. I must have had a system issue of sorts.

Comment: Have you tried compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:2.5.2@aar'

Comment: Didn't work. I found the jar file for the project though, I'm about to update the answer.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Android Studio 1.5.1. It built successfully on my machine.

Comment: download complete source from the github and add library as a module in the source, hope it will help you to remove this error.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with SSL on your system.

Try to reinstall `ca-certificates` and `ca-certificates-java` packages via `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

explanation in [artifact dependencies tutorial](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html)

Comment: I've updated the answer, but this is the error I get after making that change:       > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.

Comment: so ur first problem is solve. For this issue you must see the sync again button in top right of build.gradle file. make sure you have internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You may add in build.gradle:

```
android {
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

}

or in "Project structure"

Comment: I updated my question, but this solution didn't work - same issue.