# Adding Github repo to Android Studio Dependencies Using Maven

Tags: android, maven, github

I'm currently attempting to include [this](https://github.com/karussell/snacktory) github repository to my android studio project. I tried following the instructions given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798694/add-github-library-as-dependency-to-android-studio-project) question but to no avail.

I've added the line `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` to my project `build.gradle` as well as this line `compile 'com.github.karussell:snacktory'` to my module build.gradle file and I get a failed to resolve error. In the question that I linked earlier, it says to follow this format for adding the library `compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'` but I'm not sure what the `tag` part of it is supposed to be.

The github repo has a pom.xml file which lists other dependencies which I've been able to add without an issue. Any suggestions on how to include this particular library?

Comment: consider using this repo https://github.com/chimbori/crux for android

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://github.com/chimbori/crux) repo as suggested by @Randyka Yudhistira and it worked perfectly!