# How to use imported library project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I imported the library project following this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20497933 and now I have a libs folder with my required library.

But how do I use it in my code. I can't import `com.github.whateverlibrary` and I can't use `com.mypackagename.whateverlibrary`.

How do I reference this local library in my project?

**Edit:**

My settings.gradle file:

```
include ':libs:MyLibrary'
```

My app.gradle file:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['MyLibrary'], dir: 'libs')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21799030/6525469

Comment: @SakchhamSharma I don't want it to download it from github because I am using my own edited version of the library. So it has to use the local one

Comment: so sorry, I misunderstood the question

Comment: @SakchhamSharma That's ok, I've edited the question to be clearer for others

Comment: This Link Will Help You http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio

Comment: @DeepanshuGandhi Where does it say how to reference the library in my code. What should I write in my class file: `import ...`

Comment: yes your are right just right import statements and you are done

Comment: @DeepanshuGandhi But what do I write in my import statements. I don't want to write `import com.bumptech.glide.Glide` because that will download it from bumtech.com. I want to use the local library that I have downloaded

Comment: yes use  import yourpackagename.classname

Comment: @DeepanshuGandhi Get the error: Cannot find symbol class MyLibrary

Comment: did you library imported successfully

Comment: @DeepanshuGandhi yes, my gradle sync properly. Just can't use the files. Updated question with my gradle files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add imports from a library listed as a dependency, use the fully qualified names for the classes. For example to import from `https://github.com/bumptech/glide` you will use the names as is in the library without any modifications such as adding `com.github` or `com.yourpackagename`
To import `Glide` to your class you would use

```
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
```

see [sample projects](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/samples) for better understanding

Comment: Writing this in my class will download and import from bumptech.com? Correct? I want to use the library that I have downloaded and edited locally.

Comment: no it wont download, as you mentioned in the question that you've already added the project as a dependency, this soulution would just import.

Comment: This answers the question. The reference should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow got it working. Exact steps:

1. Download library folder from Github for the thing you want to import. For example: `testgithublibrary\library`
2. Place this folder in project root under `libs\` so the full path would be `AndroidStudioProjects\MyPackage\libs` and rename it to something else e.g. `testlocallibrary`
3. Add `compile project(':libs:testlocallibrary')` to app.gradle
4. Add `include ':libs:testlocallibrary'` to settings.gradle in root
5. Sync
6. Reference gradle with how it would have been referenced if you had got it online. Or you can just open up the library folder and see how it is: e.g. `testlocallibrary\~java\com\example\mymodule\...`