# Import the library as an existing Android code into workspace

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to import existing code [(library)](https://github.com/weixiao1984/Android-Infinite-Scroll-Listview) into Android Studio workspace according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377591/how-to-use-a-library-project-in-android-studio/20418060#20418060) guide.

A have done everything step-by-step and Gradle refuses to synchronize project with error message:

**Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed. Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.**

Any ideas what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're following an outdated guide.

You should add a new module via File -> Project Structure then click the + button.

You then have various options to import libraries.

To include your library in another project add a `compile project` definition to your dependancies:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':mylibrary')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But there's some problem. I'm trying to add that library via _File > Project Structure> + > Import Existing Project_.
And when I select the folder with library (I copied it to source folder of app in 'lib') it gives an error: **Specify location of the Gradle or Android Eclipse project**. 

I must be missing some simple thing...

Comment: Did you try and import the library folder in that Github probject?